# Is there a shortcut for "Clear Log" in DDMS?

Tags: android, ddms

I prefer to clean logs before each application run/debugging, just wondering if a shortcut for this actions is available?

p.s. Mac OS

Comment: using eclipse?. There is clear log at the top right. ir clears the log messages

Comment: @Raghunandan, Shortcut means keyboard shortcut. Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9541639/632951

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can clear logs.. in Eclipse in DDMS-->Logcat View...

Just click on clear log button as shown in image below... 
I think the view is same for both Mac and on Windows if you are using eclipse..

[image]

Hope this helps..

**EDIT:-**

- Go to Window
- Preferences.
- Then go to General -> Keys. Find the entry "Show View (View: Logcat)"
- Go to Binding and hit a key (such as <kbd>F10</kbd>)
- Apply and OK

From then after use <kbd>F10</kbd> as your shortcut.. You can personalise your shortcut as per your wish following steps I provided...

Comment: Yeah, I know, need a shortcut though.

Comment: @siik edited the post.. I have checked and verified in WIndows, should work on Mac as well...

Comment: @CRUSADER, **Clear Log**, not "Show View". How can we set a shortcut key to **clear log**?

Comment: @Pacerier  have you found that shortcut by now?